# List inside of Map, or equivalent?

Tags: smart-contracts, contract, bigmap, key

I want to have a list of data in a map so I can find it with the key which is associated with a user, but I get:

> Error: Type Error sp.TIntOrNat is not sp.TList(sp.TUnknown()) bad type
> for map value (0 : sp.TIntOrNat) is not a sp.TList(sp.TUnknown())

Is there another way of using a key to get a list, or am I just doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have another problem. The error says that you try to use an integer (here 0) as a list.